# Mysql - Sum varchar field to decimal

Tags: mysql

I have a column `total` with varchar type and I want to select all records and `sum` the total column but it doesn't sum the decimal part.

I have this values in `total column`:

```
 -----
| 5:00|
| 2:30|
| 5:00|
 -----
```

My query is that:

```
SELECT sum(cast(total as decimal(10,2))) as tudo FROM table
```

The query returns me `12.00` but should returns `12.30`.

How can I do that?

Thank you

Comment: How do you get 7.30?

Comment: '5:00' casted to decimal(10,2) is 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table (x TIME NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES('5:00:00'),('2:30:00'),('5:00:00');

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+----------+
| x        |
+----------+
| 05:00:00 |
| 02:30:00 |
| 05:00:00 |
+----------+

SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(x)))n FROM my_table;
+----------+
| n        |
+----------+
| 12:30:00 |
+----------+
```